# reduce function composed of map function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, functional-programming, reduce, map-function

Say we have

```
var i = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
```

and want to `reduce()` it like

```
var plus = function(a, b)
{
  return a + b;
};

var s = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
  .reduce(plus);

console.log(s);
```

Now, I want to compose `reduce()` function itself from `map()` function.

How would you do that? What is the smartest way?

Edit:

In the comments and answers, many have claimed `fold`/`reduce` can compose map, in shallow level, that can be true, however, in category theory, fundamentally  reduce/fold is generalized to *Catamorphism* and it's all about *functors* (`map`), and it's called *F-algebra*.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catamorphism

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-algebra

Comment: What are you talking about?

Comment: Please do not attack questions that you see randomly. When you don't understand the question, you can chose to stay away until someone smart answers.

Comment: @KenOKABE I agree with Pointy, "I want to compose reduce function itself from map function" doesn't mean anything.

Comment: @KenOKABE, you will have to explain your concept of composing a reduce function from map function. On the surface, it makes no sense.

Comment: @Pointy I guess there aren't many smart persons around ;)

Comment: I tagged `functional-programming`. In that context, should make sense.

Comment: Sorry, still a complete mystery.

Comment: @KenOKABE Can you clarify. Are you trying to build the map function using reduce (Which is possible)? Or are you trying to build the reduce function using map (which is not possible!).

Comment: @ravendano Thanks. Could you answer then, build the map function using reduce?

Comment: @KenOKABE I think it would be easier to understand if you would put the resulting array that you expect from a specific input.

Comment: @KenOKABE Done. If you want to learn about more useful functions like this I would encourage you to checkout the annotated source code for underscore js (link in my answer)

Comment: @ravendano  The question may not look sufficient to you, however, ultimately reduce/fold is composed by functor (not especially Array.map). Therefore my consideration is correct. If you don't know, study Catamorphism in F-algebra.

Comment: @plalx commented.

Comment: @Pointy commented.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 commented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to build the map function using reduce, you could do the following (The example I'm providing will use built-in functions and work for arrays only!):

```
var numbers = [1,2,3,4,5];
var map = function(arr, callback) {
  return arr.reduce(function(start, value) {
    start.push(callback(value));
    return start;
  }, []);
};

var newArray = map(numbers, function(value) {
  return value * 3;
});
console.log(newArray); // prints [3,6,9,12,15]
```

This will iterate through each of the values in our numbers array, invoke (execute) the callback function using the current value we're looping over, and then push this value to an empty array which will be returned at the end of reduce. In other words, it will map the results of our callback function to a new array!

That being said, if you're interested in functional programming, I would encourage you to check out [underscorejs's annotated source code](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html).

Comment: Thank you very much. Is there any simple explanation why only reduce can compose map, not other direction?

Comment: @KenOKABE Yes! Reduce can "fold" into any kind of data structure you want it to. It is primarily dependent on what you pass in to its initial start value and the value it returns from each callback. This is in contrast to map which only returns an array of values.

Comment: See the comment of the question.

Answer (score 1):

`map` returns one value for every value in the array, thus the result will be an array just as big as the input array. The only way to get one value out of it is by sending only one value into it.

```
[[1,2,3,4,54]].map(
    function(d){
        sum = d.reduce(function(s,d){
                     return s+d
                 });
        console.log(sum)
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks. I've got an error: app.js:6
    console.log(s)
                ^
ReferenceError: s is not defined

Comment: Sorry about that, the return of the reduce function needs to be logged.

Comment: Thanks. I understand you idea. However, this is not `reduce` composition using `map` or other direction.